# having problems with a circular import error

Tags: python, django

I have been trying to learn how to code using python and Django and  have been having a lot of fun with it but recently I have hit a little snag. I have been working on trying to fix the problem for the last few days but can't figure things out. When I try to start up the Django development server, I get the following error:

> raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name-self.urlconf_name))
>   Django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf
>   '' does not appear to
>   have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then
>   the issue is probably caused by a circular import.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to set the music app up so that when queried will send an index file.

**website.urls**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('music/', include('music.urls'))
```

**music.urls**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

path('', views.index, name="index")
```

**music.views**

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
return HttpResponse("<h1> This is my Home Page </h1>")
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
path('', views.index, name="index")
```

to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index")
]
```

You need to put your paths inside a [`urlpatterns` variable](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#example) for Django to find them.

Comment: yup, fixed my problem. thanks so much, now I can move forward.